# Could astronauts wear EVA suits in the Soyuz?

Tags: iss, soyuz-spacecraft, spacesuits, logistics

There's [a problem](http://www.spacepolicyonline.com/news/space-station-spacesuits-suffer-after-shuttle-shutdown) with maintaining the EVA suits on the space station. Since the Shuttle was canceled, only recently has Dragon made it possible to bring the suits down to ground for refurbishment, the article says. And the Dragon has had two longer interruptions and even destroyed one spacesuit on CRS-7 in 2015.

Isn't there room for one or more of three astronauts to wear an EVA suit during landing with the Soyuz, in order to bring it home? Are there other problems, like attachment to the seat?

Answer (score 11):

The Soyuz seat liners are [carefully molded to each crewperson individually by special craftsmen](https://books.google.com/books?id=ra4eCAAAQBAJ&pg=PP125&lpg=PP125&dq=soyuz%20seat%20liner%20molding&source=bl&ots=wsSDLBndza&sig=mnBt612pf0mN_gXbyP2PUIKGx2U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjb0qm8pszTAhUo0oMKHXKGAbAQ6AEISTAJ#v=onepage&q=soyuz%20seat%20liner%20molding&f=false); this is supposedly vital to successfully experiencing the shocks and accelerations of landing.

Wearing an EMU in the seat would make the seat liner not fit properly, exposing the crew person to possible injury.

[Photos of the mold process](https://www.flickr.com/photos/thom_astro/sets/72157650934017941/)

Comment: "Successfully experiencing" is a great euphemism for not being killed ;)

Comment: Why can't they mold seat to a person in an EVA suite?

Comment: Because then every crewperson would have to wear an EMU for launch and landing, and there are only a few EMUs. Sokol suits are a lot cheaper.