# How many people could the ISS support?

Tags: iss, astronauts, life-support, measurement

How many people can fit on the ISS? At what person would life support be overwhelmed?

Comment: The number of astronauts is limited by the number of simultaneously docked Soyuz capsules at the ISS. For each astronaut there should be a seat in docked Soyuz if an emergency evacuation is necessary.

Comment: @Uwe could you survive re-entry without a seat?

Comment: Highly related: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21759/how-many-times-were-there-thirteen-people-inside-the-iss-is-it-hard-on-the-stat/21760#21760 An answer there says the limit is 12.

Comment: @Muze you cannot reenter safely in a Soyuz without a custom fitted seat liner https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12926/can-a-single-soyuz-return-a-crew-of-six-back-to-earth

Comment: @OrganicMarble https://space.stackexchange.com/a/12962/18879

Comment: @Muze that answer does not address the seat liner issue. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/21310/could-astronauts-wear-eva-suits-in-the-soyuz/21312#21312

Comment: @Muze you cannot fit more than 3 people into a Soyuz. There just isn't enough room for that.

Comment: Anecdote: During video calls where all (up to ~13) astronauts onboard gather in one spot, the combined CO2 output can overwhelm the module’s life support and start to cause CO2 poisoning symptoms.

Answer (score 2):

The most that have been on the ISS at one time is 13 persons, but only for a short duration during crew changeover.  Reference: [www.space.com/6503-population-space-historic-high-13.html](http://www.space.com/6503-population-space-historic-high-13.html)

Comment: But that was with a docked Shuttle which carries its own life-support.